# Make JB Custom Activity run only once in a journey

Tags: journeybuilder, custom-activity

I am working on an activity that sends a test message that takes from another existing custom activity, and the goal is for that test message to only be sent once in a journey. As in, in a Journey with 10 contacts that would flow into the same path, the test message would only be sent once, and the contacts would still enter the other custom message activity. I've already searched for ways to make this work, like making the custom activity check a DE and alter a value so that subsequent contacts would skip through the test activity, but having to look up data in a DE each time a contact enters would have a huge impact on the Lead time.

Is there anyway possible to make a Custom Activity run only *once* for an entire Journey, or is this simply not possible to do barring the limits of a Custom Activity? Thank you for your time reading the question.